# Windows Azure:Better way to start azure for a novice developer

Tags: azure, cloud

I want to learn cloud computing, but fully novice about windows this kind of technology like windows azure and curious to learn. Can any one please help me regarding this.I don't know how and where to start. so please help me to start it by giving some good suggestions and tutorial links which will help me to start in a good way.

This kind of help is for all novice cloud computing developers who wants to learn azure.

all helps are appreciable.

**Thank You**

Comment: Have you checked out Windows Azure website (windowsazure.com)? Apart from that I would recommend checking out Windows Azure Training Kit. That has tutorials and hands-on labs to make you familiar with Windows Azure.

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks for replying.can you please give me the link where i will found this startup training kit. Is this the startup or i need to learn some other things before this. thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first one: [Azure Training Kit](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/other-resources/training-kit/)

then you have [Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/product-training/windows-azure#fbid=nCmxdtprGSK) and [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/WindowsAzure)

Comment: depends on what you want to build. Windows Azure is a broad set of cloud services. No stopping you from building java-based apps connecting to Azure services. in fact, there's a Java Dev portal for Azure: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/

Comment: thanks a lot for your help .+1 for the links..